# angularjs scroll to counter in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Need to scroll to specific element in a list if  `$index == $scope.counter` of ng-repeat.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="findA()">FIND TYPE A</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="findB()">FIND TYPE B</button>    
<ul class="feeds">
  <li ng-repeat="m in mList" ng-class="showActive($index)">{{m.s}}</li>
</ul>
```

JS:
CONTROLLER:

```
$scope.shouldScroll = true; 

$scope.mList=[{"s":3},{"s":23},{"s":33},{"s":12},{"s":31},{"s":231}];
$scope.showActive =function(index){
        /* only if scope.counter == index ,, then set the class,, 
NEED : to scroll to this element where index == counter */
   if(index == $scope.counter){
       return 'activeMarkClass';
   }
   return '';
}

$scope.findA =function(){
   $scope.counter=2;
}
$scope.findB =function(){
   $scope.counter=5;
}
```

## PROBLEM :

Whenever the `findA` and `findB` is called the css class of `li` is changed on `counter`, using `showActive`. But I also want to **scroll to this element counter**. So when `findA` is called i want **to scrollTo the the 2nd item** and to the 5th item when findB is called. Tried directives but couldn't understand how counter will be used there.

*NOTE : the counter is **also used** by some other methods in the **controller**. So can't move `counter` completely in the directive. Also **DON'T** want to do anchor scroll since already having routing url there, need a `window scroll/scrollTo`*

Answer (score 2):

You've to write a directive for that and watch for `counter` to update. As soon as it updates, your directive finds the element by index (counter) and [scrollTo](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#scrollTop-value) it.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZdunA/1/

```
myApp.directive('scrollTo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         var $body = $('body');
         scope.$watch('counter', function(newVal, oldVal) {
             if (newVal && newVal !== oldVal) {
                 $body.scrollTop(element.find('li').eq(newVal).position().top)                     
             }                 
        });
    }
  };
});
```