# Scroll to the last added record in the array within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I try to implement scroll to the last added entry whithin ngRepeat directive.

I found and investigated some related SO questions: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736647/how-to-retain-scroll-position-of-ng-repeat-in-angularjs), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941970/angularjs-scroll-to-counter-in-ng-repeat). But still can't solve the problem.

The code is pretty simple.
When the user adds new record to the array, the controller broadcasts 'scroll-event' with the new added item's name, than the directive receives this event and scroll to the new added entry in the list.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input ng-model="newItem" ng-keydown="$event.which === 13 && addNewItem(newItem)"/>
        <button ng-click="addNewItem(newItem)">Add</button>

        <div id="items-list" scroll-to-new-item> 
            <div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: 'name'">
                <input ng-model="item.name" ng-readonly="true"/>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.items = [
        {id: 1, name: "aaa"}, {id: 2, name: "bbb"},         
        {id: 3, name: "ccc"}, {id: 4, name: "ddd"},
        .......
    ];

    $scope.addNewItem = function(newItem){
        $scope.items.push({name: newItem});
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll-event', newItem);
        $scope.newItem = "";
    };
});
```

This is my directive, which should scroll to the last added record to the list.

```
app.directive("scrollToNewItem", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('scroll-event', function (event, newValue) {
                if(newValue){
                    var newItemHeightPosition = // !!! MY ISSUE HERE !!!
                    $('#items-list').animate({
                        scrollTop: newItemHeightPosition
                    }, 'slow');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

But I can't figure out, how to get the new added item's top-height position. I tried several variants, but they didn't get any results. For example the following jquery selectors doesn't work:

```
$('#items-list').find('input[value=' + newValue +']');
$('#items-list').find('input').eq(newValue);
```

Please note, that **the array is sorted in alphabetical order**, so that complicates this task.

[**This is my JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k66Za/128/).

Who knows, how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure  "$('#items-list').find('input[value=' + newValue +']');" is not written wrong? ('input[value=' + newValue +']') should probably be ('input[value="' + newValue +'"]') with the correct use of " on each side of the newValue

Comment: @NachoDawg, it doesn't matter. Still not working.

Comment: Allright. Could you explain how the dom looks after appending an item? Is the newValue variable the items class? Or an attribute?

Comment: @NachoDawg. This is the input value. You can see it in my JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k66Za/128/

Comment: @gbalduzzi. Please, read my question carefully. It doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems in that code.

1) The first problem was by the reason, that `ngRepeat` directive didn't render new added item in the repeat before `scrollToNewItem` directive started.

I've fixed it with wrapping of DOM selector in the [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout). It provides a safe method to call $scope.$apply and ensures that $digest cycle has passed. You can read more details here: [Angular $scope.$apply vs $timeout as a safe $apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070822/angular-scope-apply-vs-timeout-as-a-safe-apply).

2) The second problem was related with that my rendered input items didn't have any value-containing attributes. So, by this reason I can't find any DOM items with the following JQuery selectors.

```
$('#items-list').find('input[value=' + newValue +']')
```

I've fixed it by adding an additional attribute `value` to input whithin ngRepeat directive.

```
value="{{vehicle.Name}}"
```

Finally, my edited **JSFiddle** with the working example you can find [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/k66Za/130/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't make a case for efficiency, but unless your list numbers in the 1000, i personally don't mind using .each() like this.

```
app.directive("scrollToNewItem", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('scroll-event', function (event, newValue) {

                var newItemHeightPosition

                if (newValue) {
                    $('#items-list input').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).html().indexOf(newValue)) {
                            newItemHeightPosition = $(this).position().top;
                        }
                    })

                    $('#items-list').animate({
                        scrollTop: newItemHeightPosition
                    }, 'slow');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

To explain further, when in your own example you write

```
$('#items-list').find('input[value=' + newValue +']');
```

what you are doing is trying to select a dom-element that for example could look like this

```
<input type="submit" value="name">
```

But your input-items doesn't actually even have a value attribute. Instead, i itterate over the inputs and find the one whose html contains the name just added. It is not perfect, but it should illustrate how you can work around your problem.